# Open table row on new window?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table like:

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://www.example.com/">example</a></td>
  <td>another cell</td>
  <td>one more</td>
</tr>
```

and I am using this Javascript code:

```
$('tr').click( function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
}).hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

this Javascript is working fine making a complete row clickable and open but I want to open table row link on new window with selected size.

I have this code too:

```
<td><a href="www.example.com" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,width=1000,height=600'); return false;">Example</a></td>
```

but it's working only on the defined table cell.
So how can I create link on complete row and when user click on that row it will open in new window with defined size?

Comment: You already have the javascript to open the window in your onclick attribute. Move this to your jQuery click handler. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remove all the `onclick="` from the table rows. It should look like this now:

```
<td><a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a></td>
```

2) Change the `.click(` in your jQuery. Don't forget to return false, otherwise links will both open in a new window and current window.

```
$('tr, tr a').click( function() {
    window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'),'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,width=1000,height=600');
    return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this will do the trick (combining your snippets):

```
$('tr').click( function() {
     window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'),'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,width=1000,height=600');
}).hover( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a flag to distinct between behaviours.

```
 <tr><td><a href="http://demo.com">demo</a></td></tr>
 <tr data-flag="newWindow"><td><a href="http://demo2.com">demo2</a></td></tr>
```

And then

```
$('tr').click( function(e) {

    if($(this).attr('data-flag') == "newWindow") {
        window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'),'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,width=1000,height=600');
    } else {
         window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }
});
```